# Programmatically bind CSS classes to a kendo-dropdownlist?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I want to bind the kendo-dropdownlist to a specific class.  Essentially I need to change the appearance of the control based on certain state of the form (e.g. error, required, etc).  The logic in the model determines which classes are applied to the control.

If the model is 'error-state' then add CSS to put a box around it, if required, change border to a different state, and other business rules.

How do I programmatically bind CSS classes to a kendo-dropdownlist?
I have tried

```
[ngClass]="class_list_in_model"
-- and --
class="class_list_in_model"
```

For my text box input controls I am using [ngClass]="someproperty_in_model" and that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `[ngClass]` binding for the `<kendo-dropdownlist>` component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-dropdownlist [ngClass]="ddl_state" [data]="listItems">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
  `,
  styles: [".error-state { box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px red; }"]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public ddl_state: string = "error-state";
    public listItems: Array<string> = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
}
```

Here is a [plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zQnGMmUiPviMxmWNGnGM?p=preview) that shows this in action.